# Initialising char array of length smaller than required doesn't gives error

Tags: c++, arrays

When I declare a char array of length 2 and then input a string of length greater than 2, it doesn't give an error and outputs the whole string. Does that mean extra size is allocated dynamically?

Sample code:

```
char arr[2];
cin >> arr;
cout << arr << endl;
```

Input = "Hey"
Output = "Hey"

Comment: No, it means [that a bunch of demons just flew out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) but you haven't noticed it yet.

Comment: And still it is wrong. You access the array out of its boundaries and thats illegal (lookup : undefined behavior). C++ doesn't babysit, the fact that a program compiles doesn't mean it is correct. Anyway with C++ you should use [std::string](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-stdstring/) for dynamically allocated strings.

Comment: Your code has [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) and there's no guarantee about what it will do.

Comment: [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior)